# SpriteKit colour changes to nodes

Tags: objective-c, sprite-kit, colorize

Whilst experimenting with sprite kit I have been wondering if there is a way to change the colour of nodes in a repeated pattern (for instance red, to orange, red, orange, so on).

I have found the colorize feature below:

`[node runAction:[SKAction colorizeWithColor:[SKColor redColor] colorBlendFactor:0.8 duration:0.8]];`

Is there a way to keep changing a color in a repeated pattern? I just wonder if you could use this basic principle and just use it in a while loop?

Thank you for reading,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll can use:

```
[SKAction sequence:];
```

Which will take an array of `SKAction` objects and combine them into a single `SKAction` to run in order.

Then use:

```
[SKAction repeatActionForever:yourSequence];
```

to get them to repeat forever.